Non-Ham satellite constellation call signs
In certain public FCC documents, call signs for non-amateur satellite constellations are mentioned, e.g.:

Starlink: S2983/S3018, S3069 (Gen2)
Iridium NEXT: S2110
OneWeb: S2963

But these are not available via FCC Universal Licensing System call sign search.
Where do they come from and what are they useful for?

Perhaps the "Universal" system does not cover the FCC Space Bureau. Which, yes, makes Universal not very universal.

If those were within the ITU system of callsigns (which I strongly doubt), they would all be under the authority of Bangladesh (which "owns" the S2 and S3 prefixes), not the FCC.

@hobbs-KC2G Interestingly, ITU has a Space Services Department, but that doesn't mean that the treaties the USA is a party to recognizes its jurisdiction so your point is still valid!

Are you sure those are call signs and not satellite names?  If they were call signs and FCC was regulating them, they should start with one of A K N W.

The call signs like S2983, S3018, S3069, etc., that are mentioned for satellite constellations (such as Starlink, Iridium NEXT, and OneWeb) in public FCC documents refer to the FCC authorization numbers or SAT file numbers associated with a satellite system's licensing and operational authorization rather than traditional radio call signs used in terrestrial communications.
Where They Come From:

FCC Authorization Process for Satellites: When satellite operators apply for licenses to launch and operate their satellite constellations, they submit detailed applications to the FCC. These applications are assigned File Numbers (starting with "SAT" for satellite systems) and are often associated with specific authorization numbers. These numbers are used to track the licensing and regulatory details of that particular satellite constellation or network.

Example: Starlink's authorization numbers S2983/S3018 refer to specific licenses that authorize the launch and operation of Starlink satellites under a particular set of terms. For Starlink Gen 2, the authorization number is S3069.

SAT File Numbers in IBFS: These numbers are part of the FCC’s International Bureau Filing System (IBFS), which manages the licensing for space stations (satellites) and other international telecommunications services. You can look up these file numbers on the FCC’s IBFS system, although they are not part of the Universal Licensing System (ULS), which is mainly used for terrestrial radio systems (like amateur, broadcast, and commercial radio services).

What They Are Useful For:

Regulatory Tracking: These authorization numbers are critical for tracking the regulatory status of satellite systems, including their launch authorizations, frequencies allocated for use, and operational conditions. This allows the FCC and other regulatory bodies to ensure compliance with international treaties (like ITU regulations), coordination with other satellite systems, and adherence to specific technical and operational limits.

Public Access to Satellite Licensing Information: If you want to access specific details about a satellite constellation's authorization, such as the number of satellites approved, their altitudes, frequencies, and technical characteristics, you would reference these authorization numbers in the IBFS database. These numbers provide the key to finding all the relevant legal and technical documentation related to a particular satellite system.

Cross-Referencing in FCC Documents: In public filings, environmental assessments, and other documents related to satellite deployments, these numbers are often cited to allow for easy cross-referencing of detailed licensing information.


In summary, these numbers are unique identifiers tied to satellite authorization and licensing within the FCC’s regulatory framework and are separate from the more familiar call signs used for terrestrial communications. They provide a way to track and access information about specific satellite constellations through FCC systems like IBFS.
